# failing to npm install node-sass

Tags: python, node.js, npm, sass, prestashop

I'm currently setting up a PrestaShop local environment. but when npm installing I receive an error when it tries to install node-sass. could someone please explain how I can fix this?

[image: error]

[image: python CMD]

Comment: Do you have python installed ? and can you access it on your terminal ?

Comment: I do yes it is installed and when I type python into cmd it appears I have added another image above to prove this

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but try using a more upgraded version of node-sass or downgrade your node version. This is because for node-sass@4.11.0 only node versions <=11 are supported (your'e using 14.15.4). ref: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can occur in a few different ways, and it's generally nuanced to try to get NPM to find your existing Python correctly, but an easy fix that should work is to open an administrator PowerShell and run

`npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools`

and then

`npm install --global node-gyp`

Note that the first step will install Windows Build Tools which may be a sizeable download.